# The Big Cube and Squares Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, optimization

The following logical puzzle is mainly inspired by a mathematical contest I went to.

## Part A

You are given a cube. How many planes cross this cube by at least 3 vertices? This number will be named $n_{A}$.

## Part B

You are given a cube. Here is one of its faces.

[image]

$n_{B}$ will be its surface area.

## Part C

You are given a 5x5x5 cube with a 25 blank squares grid on each of its 6 faces.
Here is an example:

[image]

A move on one of its face consists of switching colors of 3 squares in a row — horizontally or vertically — from white to black or from black to white.

$n_{C}$ is the minimum number of moves needed so half of your cube faces is a checkerboard — like in the next diagram — and with the constraint that the total number of black squares in your cube is greater than $n_A+\dfrac{n_{B}}{2}$

[image]

Puzzle is to compute $n_C$

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native speaker, what does 'plans cross this cube by at least 3 vertices' mean?

Comment: @newbie, I'm not a native too, writing to you from France :) I tried to ask how many different [plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)) cross, or, "touch" this cube, by exactly 3 [vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry)). I recall there are 8 vertices in a cube :)

Comment: Also, in part C, does a move only affect the colors of squares in that one face (so we can treat a cube as 6 different non-interacting faces)?

Comment: Oh ok, I would call that planes, not plans :) @JKHA

Comment: @newbie, yes, each face is independent and a move is for one face only :)

Comment: Oh tank you very much! I did write planes like in French, I'm correcting it! Many thanks

Comment: For $n_B$, do you mean surface *area*?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, Yes I do :) I'm correcting it. Thank you for teaching me correct French to English math translation ;)

Comment: part C: what's a "row" ?

Comment: @Jasen It's three adjacent squares, in the same line or same column. Like in the game, "four in a row"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part A:

> $n_A=6+6+8=20$.
>  Six faces, six other axis-paralleling ones, eight non-axis-paralleling ones.
>  [image: ugly drawing]

Part B:

> $NL^2=(NT+UL)^2+UT^2=50$.
>  Surface area of one face: $S=NL^2/2=25$.
>  $n_B=6S=150$.

Part C:

> We'll first focus on making a face checkerboard-like.
>  Notice that whenever we make a move, the parity of black cells will be changed, therefore we need to make even number of moves.
>  An lowerbound of number of moves is $6$. This is because for a move of length $3$, you can 'cover' at most $2$ black squares and there're $12$ of them.
>  However, $6$ is not achieveable, because we can show by contradiction that there must be at least one 'move' that is not touching other 'move's, so that can't be a valid move (the middle cell will be black instead of white).
>  On the other hand, $8$ moves are enough.
>  [image: such a configuration]
>  Enough for the three checkboard faces. $n_A+n_B/2=20+75=95$, so the total number of black squares must be at least $96$ and the total number of black squares in three faces of checkboards is $36$. For the other three faces, there must be $60$ black cells. We can make $3$ black cells in one move, so at least we need $20$ moves. Not surprisingly, it's indeed achieveable.
>  [image: final part]
>  Therefore, $n_C=3\times 8+20=44$.

Comment: Quite a fast and correct answer :)

Comment: $n_C$ is $44$ which is quite linked to squares :)